# bash: how to expand on result?

Tags: bash

I have the following command,

```
$ echo my_{`ls | grep sh | tr '\n' ','`}
```

i.e., I intend to prefix "my_" to the name of every shell script in current directory. But it doesn't work.

```
my_{a.sh,b.sh,c.sh}
```

This is what I really want.

```
my_a.sh my_b.sh my_c.sh
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `printf`:

```
printf "my_%s\n" *.sh
```

Curly Brace i.e. `{...}` expansion doesn't allow you to use any commands inside.

Comment: Awesome solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use an array parameter expansion:

```
files=(*)
new_files=( "${files[@]/#/my_}" )
```